# XSLT to transform to HTML and format the HTML based on data in XML

Tags: c#, .net, html, xml, xslt

i am pretty new to XSLT / XML and HTML. 
I have a XML file that I currently convert to HTML in c# using an XSLT. 
The XML file represents nothing but data extracted from a table in a database.  I can currently convert the XML file to HTML using XSLT fairly easily without much formating. the HTML when opened looks pretty ordinary. 
What i intend to is format the HTML i.e change the font, background color, font color etc based on certain key values in the XML document.

The XML is generated on a daily basis using C# code . the content of the XML file totally depends on the contents of the table in the database at that point in the day when the C# code is executed..

the XML looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <defects>
    <Defectid>56</Defectid>
    <testid>111</testid>
    <summary>Release of DIT </summary>
    <DetectedDate>2011-09-21 </DetectedDate>
    <priority>2-Give High Attention</priority>
    <status>Ready to Test</status>
    <project>Business Intelligence</project>
    <assignedTo>peter</assignedTo>
    <detectedBy>john</detectedBy>
    <severity>3-Average</severity>
  </defects>
  <defects>
    <Defectid>829</Defectid>
    <testid>111</testid>
    <summary> Data request</summary>
    <DetectedDate>2012-01-12 </DetectedDate>
    <priority>3-Normal Queue</priority>
    <status>Open</status>
    <project>web</project>
    <assignedTo>tcm</assignedTo>
    <detectedBy>john</detectedBy>
    <severity>3-Average</severity>
  </defects>
  <defects>
    <Defectid>728</Defectid>
    <testid>999</testid>
    <summary>Data request</summary>
    <DetectedDate>2012-01-11</DetectedDate>
    <priority>3-Normal Queue</priority>
    <status>Fixed</status>
    <project>Business Intelligence</project>
    <assignedTo>chris</assignedTo>
    <detectedBy>peter</detectedBy>
    <severity>3-Average</severity>
  </defects>
</NewDataSet>
```

what i intend to do is generate and HTML table from this XML which would be in tabular format but the font color of the rows in the HTML table should be set based on "testid" attribute . i.e. for font color on the HTML should be unique per "testid" attribute. Since the rows per testid would change daily based on the data in the table in the database, I am not sure how this can be accomplished using XSLT.

the current XSLT looks something like this.. as you can see ,  I have hardcoded the font colors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table  BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="2" WIDTH="100">
      <tr>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" width = "70">
          <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:green">
            <b>Defect ID</b>
          </h1>
        </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" width = "70">
          <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:green">
            <b>Test ID</b>
          </h1>
        </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" width = "400">
          <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:green">
            <b>Summary</b>
          </h1>
        </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" width = "150">
          <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:green">
            <b>Detected Date</b>
          </h1>
        </td>
        <td width = "200">
          <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:green">
            <b>Priority</b>
          </h1>
        </td>
        <td width = "200">
          <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:green">
            <b>Status</b>
          </h1>
        </td>
        <td width = "200">
          <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:green">
            <b>Project</b>
          </h1>
        </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" width = "100">
          <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:green">
            <b>Assigned To</b>
          </h1>
        </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" width = "100">
          <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:green">
            <b>Detected By</b>
          </h1>
        </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" width = "80">
          <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:green">
            <b>Severity</b>
          </h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="//defects">

        <tr>
          <td width = "100">
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:blue">
              <xsl:value-of select="Defectid"></xsl:value-of>
            </h1>
          </td>
          <td width = "100">
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:blue">
              <xsl:value-of select="testid"/>
            </h1>
          </td>
          <td width = "400">
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:blue">
              <xsl:value-of select="summary"/>
            </h1>
          </td>
          <td width = "100">
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:blue">
              <xsl:value-of select="DetectedDate"/>
            </h1>
          </td>
          <td width = "100">
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:blue">
              <xsl:value-of select="priority"/>
            </h1>
          </td>
          <td width = "100">
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:blue">
              <xsl:value-of select="status"/>
            </h1>
          </td>
          <td width = "100">
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:blue">
              <xsl:value-of select="project"/>
            </h1>
          </td>
          <td width = "100">
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:blue">
              <xsl:value-of select="assignedTo"/>
            </h1>
          </td>
          <td width = "100">
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:blue">
              <xsl:value-of select="detectedBy"/>
            </h1>
          </td>
          <td width = "100">
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:blue">
              <xsl:value-of select="severity"/>
            </h1>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does anybody know or could anybody guide me?

Comment: Forgetting the whole XSLT thing for a moment - could you state the rule for choosing the colour given the testid?

Comment: How about forgetting XSLT going forward? Query your data with LINQ-to-XML, write some trivial functions to ensure your HTML output is escaped and valid.. You'll have a flexible and program in a language everybody can read in 1/3rd of the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a solution that applies up to 20 different colors - applying one particular color for each row with a specific testid.
Note that it is not important how many distinct testid's occur. Also note that color coding says nothing about the testid itself - but that's exactly the way you wanted it :-).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:std="http://www.standardColors.com">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:variable name="colors">
        <color>#0000FF</color>
        <color>#FF0000</color>
        <color>#00FFFF</color>
        <color>#FFFF00</color>
        <color>#347C2C</color>
        <color>#800080</color>
        <color>#3B9C9C</color>
        <color>#A52A2A</color>
        <color>#3BB9FF</color>
        <color>#FF00FF</color>
        <color>#6698FF</color>
        <color>#808000</color>
        <color>#8D38C9</color>
        <color>#ADD8E6</color>
        <color>#F660AB</color>
        <color>#F87217</color>
        <color>#F9B7FF</color>
        <color>#FFA500</color>
        <color>#FFE87C</color>
        <color>#8E35EF</color>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="testIDs" select="distinct-values(//testid)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="colorList">
        <xsl:for-each select="$testIDs">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position() mod 20"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$colors/color[$pos]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    th, td {
                        border: solid black 1px ;
                        padding: 3px;                       
                        border-spacing:2px;
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        width: 100px;
                    }
                    th {
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        color:green;
                        align:center;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                    }
                    <xsl:for-each select="$testIDs">
                    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                     tr.testid<xsl:value-of select="."/> {
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        font-weight:bold;
                        color:<xsl:value-of select="$colorList/color[$pos]"/>;
                        align:center
                    }
                   </xsl:for-each>
                </style>
            </head>                
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/NewDataSet/defects[1]/*">
                            <th>
                                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                            </th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet/defects">
        <tr>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">testid<xsl:value-of select="testid"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I applied this on the below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <defects>
    <Defectid>56</Defectid>
    <testid>111</testid>
    <summary>Release of DIT </summary>
    <DetectedDate>2011-09-21 </DetectedDate>
    <priority>2-Give High Attention</priority>
    <status>Ready to Test</status>
    <project>Business Intelligence</project>
    <assignedTo>peter</assignedTo>
    <detectedBy>john</detectedBy>
    <severity>3-Average</severity>
  </defects>
  <defects>
    <Defectid>829</Defectid>
    <testid>111</testid>
    <summary> Data request</summary>
    <DetectedDate>2012-01-12 </DetectedDate>
    <priority>3-Normal Queue</priority>
    <status>Open</status>
    <project>web</project>
    <assignedTo>tcm</assignedTo>
    <detectedBy>john</detectedBy>
    <severity>3-Average</severity>
  </defects>
  <defects>
    <Defectid>728</Defectid>
    <testid>999</testid>
    <summary>Data request</summary>
    <DetectedDate>2012-01-11</DetectedDate>
    <priority>3-Normal Queue</priority>
    <status>Fixed</status>
    <project>Business Intelligence</project>
    <assignedTo>chris</assignedTo>
    <detectedBy>peter</detectedBy>
    <severity>3-Average</severity>
  </defects>
  <defects>
    <Defectid>728</Defectid>
    <testid>321</testid>
    <summary>Data request</summary>
    <DetectedDate>2012-01-11</DetectedDate>
    <priority>3-Normal Queue</priority>
    <status>Fixed</status>
    <project>Business Intelligence</project>
    <assignedTo>chris</assignedTo>
    <detectedBy>peter</detectedBy>
    <severity>3-Average</severity>
  </defects>
  <defects>
    <Defectid>728</Defectid>
    <testid>457</testid>
    <summary>Data request</summary>
    <DetectedDate>2012-01-11</DetectedDate>
    <priority>3-Normal Queue</priority>
    <status>Fixed</status>
    <project>Business Intelligence</project>
    <assignedTo>chris</assignedTo>
    <detectedBy>peter</detectedBy>
    <severity>3-Average</severity>
  </defects>
  <defects>
    <Defectid>728</Defectid>
    <testid>202</testid>
    <summary>Data request</summary>
    <DetectedDate>2012-01-11</DetectedDate>
    <priority>3-Normal Queue</priority>
    <status>Fixed</status>
    <project>Business Intelligence</project>
    <assignedTo>chris</assignedTo>
    <detectedBy>peter</detectedBy>
    <severity>3-Average</severity>
  </defects>
</NewDataSet>
```

And got as result

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
                    th, td {
                        border: solid black 1px ;
                        padding: 3px;                       
                        border-spacing:2px;
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        width: 100px;
                    }
                    th {
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        color:green;
                        align:center;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                    }

                     tr.testid111 {
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        font-weight:bold;
                        color:#0000FF;
                        align:center
                    }

                     tr.testid999 {
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        font-weight:bold;
                        color:#FF0000;
                        align:center
                    }

                     tr.testid321 {
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        font-weight:bold;
                        color:#00FFFF;
                        align:center
                    }

                     tr.testid457 {
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        font-weight:bold;
                        color:#FFFF00;
                        align:center
                    }

                     tr.testid202 {
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        font-weight:bold;
                        color:#347C2C;
                        align:center
                    }
                   </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Defectid</th>
                <th>testid</th>
                <th>summary</th>
                <th>DetectedDate</th>
                <th>priority</th>
                <th>status</th>
                <th>project</th>
                <th>assignedTo</th>
                <th>detectedBy</th>
                <th>severity</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="testid111">
                <td>56</td>
                <td>111</td>
                <td>Release of DIT </td>
                <td>2011-09-21 </td>
                <td>2-Give High Attention</td>
                <td>Ready to Test</td>
                <td>Business Intelligence</td>
                <td>peter</td>
                <td>john</td>
                <td>3-Average</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="testid111">
                <td>829</td>
                <td>111</td>
                <td> Data request</td>
                <td>2012-01-12 </td>
                <td>3-Normal Queue</td>
                <td>Open</td>
                <td>web</td>
                <td>tcm</td>
                <td>john</td>
                <td>3-Average</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="testid999">
                <td>728</td>
                <td>999</td>
                <td>Data request</td>
                <td>2012-01-11</td>
                <td>3-Normal Queue</td>
                <td>Fixed</td>
                <td>Business Intelligence</td>
                <td>chris</td>
                <td>peter</td>
                <td>3-Average</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="testid321">
                <td>728</td>
                <td>321</td>
                <td>Data request</td>
                <td>2012-01-11</td>
                <td>3-Normal Queue</td>
                <td>Fixed</td>
                <td>Business Intelligence</td>
                <td>chris</td>
                <td>peter</td>
                <td>3-Average</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="testid457">
                <td>728</td>
                <td>457</td>
                <td>Data request</td>
                <td>2012-01-11</td>
                <td>3-Normal Queue</td>
                <td>Fixed</td>
                <td>Business Intelligence</td>
                <td>chris</td>
                <td>peter</td>
                <td>3-Average</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="testid202">
                <td>728</td>
                <td>202</td>
                <td>Data request</td>
                <td>2012-01-11</td>
                <td>3-Normal Queue</td>
                <td>Fixed</td>
                <td>Business Intelligence</td>
                <td>chris</td>
                <td>peter</td>
                <td>3-Average</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

which in a browser looks as follows:

[image: table view]

**ADDED variant using key**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:std="http://www.standardColors.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="std">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:variable name="colors">
        <color>#0000FF</color>
        <color>#FF0000</color>
        <color>#00FFFF</color>
        <color>#FFFF00</color>
        <color>#347C2C</color>
        <color>#800080</color>
        <color>#3B9C9C</color>
        <color>#A52A2A</color>
        <color>#3BB9FF</color>
        <color>#FF00FF</color>
        <color>#6698FF</color>
        <color>#808000</color>
        <color>#8D38C9</color>
        <color>#ADD8E6</color>
        <color>#F660AB</color>
        <color>#F87217</color>
        <color>#F9B7FF</color>
        <color>#FFA500</color>
        <color>#FFE87C</color>
        <color>#8E35EF</color>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!--<xsl:variable name="testIDs" select="distinct-values(//testid)"/>-->

    <xsl:key name="testidKey" match="testid" use="text()"/>

    <xsl:variable name="colorList">
        <xsl:for-each select="//testid">
            <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('testidKey', text())[1])">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position() mod 20"/>
                <color>
                    <xsl:attribute name="testid"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$colors/color[$pos]"/>
                </color>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    th, td {
                        border: solid black 1px ;
                        padding: 3px;                       
                        border-spacing:2px;
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        width: 100px;
                    }
                    th {
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        color:green;
                        align:center;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                    }
                    <xsl:for-each select="$colorList/color">
                     tr.testid<xsl:value-of select="@testid"/> {
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        font-weight:bold;
                        color:<xsl:value-of select="."/>;
                        align:center
                    }
                   </xsl:for-each>
                </style>
            </head>                
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/NewDataSet/defects[1]/*">
                            <th>
                                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                            </th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet/defects">
        <tr>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">testid<xsl:value-of select="testid"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**MSXML error prevention (and any other xsl engine used)**

see [convert RTF into node-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841318/build-node-set-variable-from-result-tree-fragment-using-xslchoose) and [RTF to node-set generic approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837589/result-tree-fragment-to-node-set-generic-approach-for-all-xsl-engines) for further details.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:std="http://www.standardColors.com"
    xmlns:exslt="http://www.exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="std">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <std:colors>
        <color>#0000FF</color>
        <color>#FF0000</color>
        <color>#00FFFF</color>
        <color>#FFFF00</color>
        <color>#347C2C</color>
        <color>#800080</color>
        <color>#3B9C9C</color>
        <color>#A52A2A</color>
        <color>#3BB9FF</color>
        <color>#FF00FF</color>
        <color>#6698FF</color>
        <color>#808000</color>
        <color>#8D38C9</color>
        <color>#ADD8E6</color>
        <color>#F660AB</color>
        <color>#F87217</color>
        <color>#F9B7FF</color>
        <color>#FFA500</color>
        <color>#FFE87C</color>
        <color>#8E35EF</color>
    </std:colors>

    <xsl:variable name="colors" select="document('')/*/std:colors"/>

    <xsl:key name="testidKey" match="testid" use="text()"/>

    <xsl:variable name="std:colorList">
        <xsl:for-each select="//testid">
            <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('testidKey', text())[1])">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position() mod 20"/>
                <xsl:element name="color">
                    <xsl:attribute name="testid"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$colors/color[$pos + 1]"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    table {
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        font-weight:bold;
                        align:center;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                    }
                    th, td {
                        border: solid black 1px ;
                        padding: 3px;                       
                        border-spacing:2px;
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        width: 100px;
                    }
                    th {
                        color:green;
                    }
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="function-available('msxsl:node-set')">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($std:colorList)/color" mode="addTRclassToCSS"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="function-available('exslt:node-set')">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($std:colorList)/color" mode="addTRclassToCSS"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:variable name="colorList" select="$std:colorList"/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="$colorList" mode="addTRclassToCSS"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>

                </style>
            </head>                
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/NewDataSet/defects[1]/*">
                            <th>
                                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                            </th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet/defects">
        <tr>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">testid<xsl:value-of select="testid"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="color" mode="addTRclassToCSS">
                    tr.testid<xsl:value-of select="@testid"/> {
                    color:<xsl:value-of select="."/>;
                    }
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Maestro13, the final solution is exactly what I need.. but there is one problem.. i am using c# .net 4.0 to create xml and loading xslt and transforming the xml file. the distinct-value() is not supported :-(. Is there a xslt 1.0 solution to this problem?

Comment: yes, you can also use a key - see addition under ** ADDED variant using key **

Comment: Nice solution Maestro - I was struggling to work out how to do the distinct-value to color mapping :applause:

Comment: Maestro, your code looks good, but there is one problem , i can't get my head around the problem. whenever I run the c# code, i am getting the following error .. "XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set. " i tried commenting out sections from your code , tried few changes but nothing works.. i have spent over 8 hrs on this problem.. do you think this is a .net issue or the xsl issue?

Comment: @bcd I managed to change the code so that MSXML 3.0/4.0/6.0 will not error any more. See **MSXML error prevention** above. I have some questions left, but I will open a new thread for that :-). In particular: it now works fine for MSXML, but built in xsl engine in XML Spy now errors :-(.

Comment: Maestro, i used your xslt ( the one with the key added) and used XslCompiledTransform class , instead of the XslTransform class in my C# code Now, i get the following error.. "To use a result tree fragment in a path expression, first convert it to a node-set using the msxsl:node-set() function." .... If i have to use MSXML, then i will have to download msxml and reference it in my code, which I want to avoid. i am currently using the system.xml and system.xml.xsl namespace in .NET

Comment: @bcd never-ending story is it? I will revise the answer now that I have a full answer on the other thread - I hope that will be my final edit! :-) Not sure what difference it made using another class though... do you know which xsl engines are behind those classes? It's not MSXML after all?

Comment: Maestro13.. you are awesome!! thank you for your perseverance and patience

Comment: Maestro13, no errors in c# now, but the colors are not applied except for the header (green color). I am looking into your xslt to see if there is something missing.

Comment: @bcd try saving the end result html in a file and check its contents, in particular whether the css testidxxx class defs look OK. I opened it with all browser types and got the correct result. That leaves two possible explanations: (1) your browser version does not support CSS (2) your xsl engine is just a little pickier about the template input - for instance try removing /color from the part where css lines are generated. By the way, I have been deleting comments that are mereley us ping-ponging progress reports; I suggest you do the same.

Comment: @bcd one other possible explanation: I checked msdn for .net XslCompinedTransform class info ([xslcompiledtransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)), and found the following remark: "Support for the XSLT document() function and embedded script blocks are disabled by default. These features can be enabled by creating an XsltSettings object and passing it to the Load method." As I am using the document function, it seems you will have to activate it in your code.

Comment: Maestro,  the problem seems to be with outlook 2007. i am actually embedding the HTML doc into the body of an email i am trying to send out from .net . on various other browsers, the document looks fine. i will look into it from here on . thanks so much for your help

Comment: just an fyi, the problem seems to the outlook 2007 client. when I open the email body in outlook 2007, i dont see the borders but when i open through Internet explorer --> webmail , the email body shows up fine. when i open the email through webmail through Chrome, i see only colors but no borders.. anyway.. i will figure it out

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following your scenario correctly, here's what I suggest:

Use the data from your XML "testid" element as the value for a class attribute that you assign to your `<h1>` tags in your XSLT.  Then use css to define the colors that are used with the particular testid values.

Since in your sample your "testid" values are all numbers, do remember to give a hard-coded alphabetic prefix to the class name.  CSS doesn't like class names beginning with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Making the assumption that testid's 111 should be blue and all others red then try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    h1.header{
                        font-family:verdana;
                        font-size:60%;
                        color:green                    
                    }
                    h1.testid111 {
                    font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:blue
                    }
                    h1.testid999 {
                    font-family:verdana ;font-size:60%;color:red
                    }
                </style>
            </head>                
            <body>
                <table BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="2" WIDTH="100">
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/NewDataSet/defects[1]/*">
                            <td nowrap="nowrap" width="70">
                                <h1 class="header">
                                    <b>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                                    </b>
                                </h1>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
   </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet/defects">
        <xsl:variable name="class">
            <xsl:text>testid</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="testid"/>
        </xsl:variable>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <td nowrap="nowrap" width = "70">
                        <h1 class='{$class}'>
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </b>
                        </h1>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Kevan, can we put a large list of colors in an array or list of something like that and use those  to assign to rows per unique testid. i dont expect more than 15 unique testid's in the table. in your example you have hardcoded the testid.

Comment: I've modded my answer to use redlena's css style idea - all you now need to do is extend the list of css styles in the header - does that work for you?

Comment: Kevan, thanks for the pointers. unfortunately the code you provided doesn't meet my needs. the values in testid are not the same time each time my code executes. today it could be 111, 999 . tomorrow, it could be 231, 456, 569 etc. I don't expect more than 15 distinct testid's in my file but the actual values of the testid would change from day to day. is there a way to put, lets say , 15 different colors into a array/list and apply 1 color per testid ?