# How do I know how many tags an xsl:variable contains?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

In XSLT 1.0, if I have an `<xsl:variable>` declared like that:

```
<xsl:variable name="ListeEcheances">
    <bla/><bli/>
</xsl:variable>
```

How do I know if it's empty? Or even better: how do I know how many tags it contains? (I know there are 2 tags here, but my real code is a little bit more complex :))

`<xsl:when test="$ListeEcheances=''">` returns `true` (it doesn't count the tags, only the text) ;

`<xsl:when test="count($ListeEcheances/*) > 0">` sadly doesn't compile.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This talk of tags is very confusing. XSLT doesn't deal with tags, it deals with nodes. If it were `<xsl:var><b></b><c><d/></c></xsl:var>`, would that be 5 tags (two start tags, two end tags, and an empty tag)?

Comment: Correct, I should have written: "how many children directly under my variable?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed incorrect and your compiler is correct in throwing an error. You can only count a node set, you [cannot count a result tree fragment](https://blogs.oracle.com/rammenon/entry/result_tree_fragments_and_node). What you need is transform the variable in a node-set by using an extension function.

For Saxon 6.5 this would be exsl:node-set.This works with Saxon 6.5 and any processor that supports the [EXSLT node-set](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) function (most do). EDIT: Jirka Kosek wrote down a list of [node-set extensions per processor](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html), I'm sure yours is in the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">

    <xsl:variable name="ListeEcheances">
        <bla/><bli/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(exsl:node-set($ListeEcheances)/*) > 0">
                <xsl:text>Larger then zero!</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>Larger then zero!
```

Note: if you were to use XSLT 2.0, everything is a node-set and you don't run into this awkwardness of XSLT 1.0, where result tree fragments are next to useless.

Answer (score 2):

Try `<xsl:when test="count($ListeEcheances/*) > 0">`

or wait - maybe you get something like

`Expression must evaluate to a node-set.`
`count(-->$ListeEcheances<--/*) > 0`

The reason is that the variable is a result tree fragment, not a node-set.
In XSLT 1.0 you will need to apply the node-set function, available in a namespace dependent on the processor.
For instance: `<xsl:when test="count(msxsl:node-set($ListeEcheances/*)) > 0">`

If that does not work, or if you can't discover the namespace to use, then a trick might help:

`<xsl:variable name="temp" select="$ListeEcheances"/>`
`<xsl:when test="count($temp/*) > 0">`

The reason that this works can be found in [stackoverflow rtf to node-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841318/build-node-set-variable-from-result-tree-fragment-using-xslchoose/9844146#9844146)

Comment: Oops, typo in my question, it's what I wanted to write. So it doesn't compile.

Comment: it does for me - maybe your xslt processor is a little picky, then try using `&gt;` instead of >

Comment: Whether I use `>`or `&gt;`I always get: `JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Erreur de controle du type de l'expression 'FilterParentPath(variable-ref(ListeEcheances/result-tree), step("child", 1))'`

Comment: @ThomasLulé: (and @Maestro13) you cannot use a result tree fragment as argument for the `count()` expression. See my answer for a possible solution, depending on your processor. `msxsl:node-set($ListeEcheances/*)` will not work either, because (1) this is JAXP, so MS extensions won't work and (2) you must use the node-set function on the _variable_  not on the expression. PS: I like the little trick with `$temp` though! ;)

Comment: @Abel agreed - wrong placement of parenthesis - should have been `msxsl:node-set($ListeEcheances)/*` but as you said msxsl is not available in the processor that ThomasLulé uses.

Comment: OK I could make it work by adding the exsl namespace! (the trick with $temp didn't work for a reason or another...). Thanks a lot for your help, you 2!

Answer (score 2):

If the content of the variable is declared in the XSLT as shown in your example, rather than dynamically evalueated, you can use the `document()` function to parse the XSLT file(which is an XML file) and evaluate an XPath expression to count the elements in the variable:

```
count(document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='ListeEcheances']/*)
```

Using the document function with an empty path will load the base URI of the current stylesheet.

Comment: Yes, a lovely approach, it's the way I often specify XSLT unit tests by letting them operate on themselves. Saves the trouble of maintaining two files for one test.