# XSLT: copy few nodes only of xml to a variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there a way to copy 2 or 3 nodes of XML to a variable using XSLT?  I'm looking for nodes and not the node values.

My sample XML is:

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node3>abc</node3> 
    <node4>def</node4> 
  </node2>
</node1>
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node3>123</node3> 
    <node4>456</node4> 
  </node2>
</node1>
```

And my XSLT sample is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/node1/node2">
  <xsl:if test="current()/node4 ! = '456'">
    <xsl:copy-of select="./node3" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="./node4" />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:foreach>
```

The problem with this is that I'm getting `node4` everytime as the first node of the XML instead of current one. On `node3` I'm getting the current one and there's no problem.

Comment: my output should be values of node3 and node4 as a flat file, and duplicates should be eliminated. And also it should perform really fast, as the input is huge like 20MB.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be caused by the RTF(Resulting Tree Fragment) problem of XSLT-1.0:

> A variable cannot contain a nodeset (but only a RTF)

I explained this problem in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37031682/1305969).

RTFs cannot be queried by XPath-1.0 expressions, so they are only useful in a very limited subset of situations.

One solution would be using [the newer XSLT-2.0](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/04/10/xslt2.html).

Comment: Thank you @zx485. Is there any workaround for this problem instead of using xslt 2.0?

Comment: @rgu: Unfortunately none that I know of :-( Otherwise I would have included that in my answer.

Comment: You can convert a rtf to a node-set using the node-set function.  See the link:
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html

Answer (score 0):

It may help you to just select the nodes that you want all at once.

```
<xsl:variable name="sample">
   <xsl:copy-of select="/node1/node2[node4!='456']/*[name()='node3' or name()='node4']"/>
</xsl:variable>
```